# Make an image width 100% of parent div, but not bigger than its own width

Tags: html, width, css

I’m trying to get an image (dynamically placed, with no restrictions on dimensions) to be as wide as its parent div, but only as long as that width isn’t wider than its own width at 100%. I’ve tried this, to no avail:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Many of these images are way wider than their parent div, which is why I’d like them to resize accordingly, but when a small image pops in there and gets scaled up beyond its normal dimensions, it really looks terrible. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What happens if you only specify `max-width: 100%` ?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - Give that as an answer and I'll vote for you.

Comment: It would be well to consider which browsers support max-width, though.

Comment: kbrimington does bring a good point to the table. According to

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width#compatibilitysection

IE8’s implementation is buggy.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Just specify `max-width: 100%` alone, that should do it.

Comment: Chromium seems to simply leave it at 100% regardless of context. Perhaps I should stop constantly looking at my work on beta software. Thank you!

Comment: How do you do this without using max-width: 100%. In React-Native, it's not possible to use percentages.

Comment: @Croolsby you can use percentage in react-native, but with string value, like this '100%'

Answer (score 13):

Found this post on a Google search, and it solved my issue thanks to @jwal reply, but I made one addition to his solution.

```
img.content.x700 {
  width: auto !important; /*override the width below*/
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 678px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

With the above I changed the max-width to the dimensions of the content container that my image is in. In this case it is: container width - padding - boarder = max width

This way my image won't break out of the containing div, and I can still float the image within the content div.

I've tested in IE 9, FireFox 18.0.2 and Chrome 25.0.1364.97, Safari iOS and seems to work.

Additional: I tested this on an image 1024px wide displayed at 678px (the max width), and an image 500px wide displayed at 500px (width of the image).

Comment: Using `width:auto !important;` fixed an issue in IE11 for me where the image would be larger than its container and IE11 not scaling down the image. Setting this in the `img` selector sorted the issue in IE11. However setting `width:100%;` without the other rule did nothing in IE11. So the "override" has to be included for the image to scale down to its container's size.

Answer (score 4):

Setting a width of 100% is the full width of the div it's in, not the original full-sized image. There is no way to do that without JavaScript or some other scripting language that can measure the image. If you can have a fixed width or fixed height of the div (like 200px wide) then it shouldn't be *too* hard to give the image a range to fill. But if you put a 20x20 pixel image in a 200x300 pixel box it will still be distorted.

Comment: please provide a working example whenever possible. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/) is recommended. :)

Answer (score 3):

> In line style - this works for me every time

```
<div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="/theImg.jpg" style="max-width: 100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code:

```
div.image {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}

div.image img {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the max width and if you want you can also set some padding on one of the sides. In my case the max-width: 100% was good but the image was right next to the end of the screen.

```
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  /*add more paddings if needed*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem, but I set the height value in my CSS to *auto* and that fixed my problem. Also, don't forget to do the display property.

```
  #image {
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      max-height: 550px;
      max-width: 1200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
 }
```

Comment: just a fyi..you can remove the height:auto and width:auto.  the max-height and max-width is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which worked for me and can be found in the following link:

[Full Width Containers in Limited Width Parents](https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/)

Answer (score 0):

I found `max-width:inherit;` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: fit-content;` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If the image is smaller than parent...

```
.img_100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I would use the property `display: table-cell`

Here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Formal_syntax)