# CSS max-width to match parent width

Tags: css, width, overflow

I am having a problem with the width of a code block I have inside of a list element. This list element is set by JavaScript, as it is used with Swipejs, to the width of the page.

However, the problem I have is that when the `<pre>` element has got a large block of text on a single line that surpasses the width of the parent, the list element expands. My question would be how can I prevent this from happening and force the `<pre>` element to have a set width to the `<li>` width while having `overflow:scroll`?

```
<li>
<pre class="language-css"><code class="language-css">
</code></pre>
</li>
```

I am aware that this can be done by defining a specific fixed width to the `<pre>` element but as it should work with different screen sizes, this is not possible. I hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Make it `display:block`? Blocks stretch to fill space horizontally by default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463664/make-an-image-width-100-of-parent-div-but-not-bigger-than-its-own-width