# CSS Image height restrict to parent div height. Parent div width and height are specified in percentages***

Tags: html, image, css

How to restrict the height of an image to its parent container whose height is specified in terms of percentages?

I want the image to span over the parent if image width/height > parent width/height.
and image to be center aligned to parent if image width/height < parent width/height.
In any case I dont want the image to be stretched[vertically/horizontall.]

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#top{
    height:10%;
}

#middle{
    height:80%;
}

#bottom{
    height:10%;
}

img{
    width: how much?
    height: how much?
}
```

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="top">I am top</div>
        <div id="middle">
            <img src="/images/abc.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">I am bottom</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I request that this question be UNMARKED as duplicate??

Comment: Reopen vote. But it _is_  a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19193223/2888561

Comment: How is this a duplicate question?
I wanted the parent to be a generic container [without fixed width or height!]
More over, the solution I approved is using width:"auto" and height:100% to avoid image stretching.
The questions suggested gives solution for a fixed width and height parent container.

Comment: The container doesn't matter, the problem is the contained. `width: auto` _should_ be default, anyway.

Comment: I am afraid but that is not the solution that I want
And width auto was not default on Chrome latest browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Just define the image height as a percentage, auto width will keep it in proportion.

Comment: That was partly helpful.
The image width is getting stretched.
Eg: my browser is 1366*768.
My middle div is 80% height = 614px.
My image is 1600*1600 px.
When I set height:100%, the width is getting stretched. How to avoid this?

Comment: Perfect! width: auto; made the magic!

Comment: In my case, it was fine without `width: auto;`.

Comment: not work for me (