# CSS adjusting percentage widths not capping image size

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to make the image fit into the  banner, shown by the grey area. According to my understanding, setting 100% on img height would cause its height to be 100% of its container's height, that is the div. However, clearly, the image is not resizing based on the height of the div section.

There must be a very basic answer to this, but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  div {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 5%;
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  
  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="https://mat3e.github.io/brains/img/3.jpg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pasting my comment below here:
[CSS: How can I set image size relative to parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192892/css-how-can-i-set-image-size-relative-to-parent-height)

In response to this link, adding a fixed height is demonstrated in the asker's code, I did not find it immediately obvious that my mistake was not adding a fixed height to *any* of the outer containers relative to img (in my case, ). I actually realised adding a fixed size to  works as well, but I did not want to, because I wished to keep the height as a percentage.

Comment: Here's an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192892/css-how-can-i-set-image-size-relative-to-parent-height

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: How can I set image size relative to parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192892/css-how-can-i-set-image-size-relative-to-parent-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give at least the body a fixed height.
Have a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-flower-jhf5k). I edited your code so it works for you.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I'm looking for. @Marfee While the link you referred me to does indicate adding a fixed height, I did not find it immediately obvious that my mistake was not adding a fixed height to any of the outer containers relative to img (in my case, <body>). I actually realised adding a fixed size to <div> works as well, but I did not want to, because I wished to keep the height as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-height: inherit;` in `img` tag. How your height of your image will adjust to the size of the parent.

```css
div {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 5%;
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  
  img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="https://mat3e.github.io/brains/img/3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Am I correct to say that this will only work for images with original height >= 100px?

Comment: In my example, the `height` of the image is always adjusted to your gray `div`. The `height` of your `div` in `height: 5%;` adjusts to `max-height: 100px;`.