# Image width the same as parent element?

Tags: css

I have an image which I need to a max width as its parent element.

With this code the image is shown with a width of 600px. I need the image to have a width equal to 400px, even though the natural width of the image is 600px.

How can I do this?

```
<div style="width: 400px">
   <table>
    <tr><td>
      <img widht="600" ..../>
   </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have this css:

```
table, img
{max-width:100%}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an image width 100% of parent div, but not bigger than its own width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463664/make-an-image-width-100-of-parent-div-but-not-bigger-than-its-own-width)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 img{  width: 100%; }
```

will sort you out.
This will 'expand' the image width the the size of the containing element.

Comment: I works but then the image loss its proportion since the height remain the original one. I need the height to be recalculate based in its width.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your `width` attribute in `img`. Then follow it up with `max-width:100%` and that should do it.

Comment: Agreed. The problem isn't that your not declaring a size in your CSS. It's that you're overriding it within your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the parent-img relationship, you dont need a table...in that case..

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BNP4/)

HTML

```
<div>
   <img src='http://www.mibz.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/tesla-model-s-large-3.jpg' />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:200px;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that my image element has the property: height like: <img height="500" src='http://www.mibz.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/tesla-model-s-large-3.jpg' /> in your code in fiddle.