# Is it possible to style an image added by the "content" property

Tags: css

Here is my code:

```css
#my_div:before
{
  /* displaying the image */
  content: url("img path");
  /* centering the image */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* making the image responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

I'm trying to make the image responsive through the `max-width:100%` property but it is not working

**My Question**: Is it possible to do such a thing?

### Edit

The question is not a duplicate, I want the dimensions to scale automatically on screen resize while the other question sets a fixed size to the image

Comment: Yes. http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-css-tricks/

Comment: @JoshSalazar I'm not looking for a way to do it through the **img** tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the height of an image in CSS :before/:after pseudo-elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977957/can-i-change-the-height-of-an-image-in-css-before-after-pseudo-elements)

Comment: @AbdoAdel , it doesn't have to be through the image tag. You can apply it to anything, really. You can apply it to your my_div id just as easy as you can apply it to the img tag. If your other styles are working in your css, try adding height: auto. If they're not working, try removing the :before pseudo-element and then adding height:auto.

Comment: @JoshSalazar and that's what exactly I did, I used `max-width` for `#my_div` but it didn't work

Comment: @AbdoAdel, right. I see that. I'm going to make an answer so I can format things better...

Comment: @AbdoAdel can you use jquery for it.? but you need to edit demo html code dude

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara yes I can do it through jQuery, I can do it also through img tag + css , but I don't want to use that, My question is just about the possibility of something

Comment: @AbdoAdel then what should it take initial **width:???** you can try that by  adding **width:100% or  auto** to the class may it will work for you

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara didn't work :D, seems like I'm gonna use jquery at the end :D

Comment: @AbdoAdel hahaha thats why i directly asked for even you can refer **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463664/make-an-image-width-100-of-parent-div-but-not-bigger-than-its-own-width**

Comment: Can you inspect element and check how the image is being rendered in the browser?
if there in an `<img>` tag , then try using `#my_div:before img` selector and set `max-width:100%`

Comment: @SoorajChandran This is not PHP or java script, the DOM remains the same for the **"content"** property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#my_div:before
{
  /* displaying the image */
  content: url("img path");
  /* centering the image */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* making the image responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If this doesn't work, try removing the :before pseudo-element

```
#my_div
{
  /* displaying the image */
  content: url("img path");
  /* centering the image */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  /* making the image responsive */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Without seeing the context of your html, this is the best solution I can offer. We'll need more information in order to understand your situation better.

Comment: you can't also remove the **before pseudo-element**, that will stop the content

Answer (score 0):

I confess I'm not entirely sure what effect you are after but I think this might be a better option for you.

Don't put the image in the `content` property...make that pseudo-element 100% size of the div and use a background image.

A couple of options for you.

```css
.my_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 1em auto;

}

.my_div:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover:before {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div"></div>

<div class="my_div cover"></div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cabow4zg/1/)

Comment: I will try it and give you feedback