# How to change dimensions of all images present in a specified div

Tags: php, html, image, css

I am trying to make all images width as 100% present in a div with name "res". Here is the code I used but its not working in mobile. Can anyone suggest me the better code.

For more clarity check the [page](http://www.justforfun.ind.in/view.php?post_id=1521962612)

PHP CODE

```
<?php
      echo '<div class="res"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>';
?>
```

CSS CODE

```
div.res>img
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<body>
<?php require 'test.php'; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: No no. I'm not clicking that link and also this seems to be a css issue

Comment: you didn't close the div....  `'<div class="res"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>'`  however that alone may not fix it. you may have to use javascript.  images can be finicky

Comment: Sorry while posting question I forget to close.

Comment: probably the div needs it's size defined, as it will suffer from shrinkage...  But you might have to use some other CSS, I would have to do some testing and I feel to lazy right now. 100% of the div, with no width is the width of the image or something like that.  Width is based on the parents width...

Comment: This is a somewhat related question, but not an exact duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463664/make-an-image-width-100-of-parent-div-but-not-bigger-than-its-own-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few issues with your code, here is the markup I see on your page :

```
<div class="res">
    <h3>
        <img src="image.jpeg" style="width: 576.766px; height: 384.532px;">
    </h3>
</div>
```

The image tag is embedded in a h3 tag, meaning that your css selector `.res>img {}` won't work. You are here targeting the direct children img tags of the `.res` div, **not all** the img tags included in that div. What you want to do is to use a selector like `.res img {}`

Secondly, you are using inline styles in your img tag which are preceding over your css, meaning that your css stylesheet will be ignored in that case.

To conclude, here are the steps to resolve your problems :

- Try to avoid embedding images in a h3 tag as it has no semantic
  meaning in that case
- Fix your css selector to correctly target the
  images
- Remove the inline styles
- Bonus : try not to base-64 encode
  large PNG files for performance purposes, but that is another
  story...