# Image should shrink but not grow above it's natural size

Tags: css, image, flexbox, size

I want an image to shrink but not grow above it's natural size. The solution given here is working fine:
[Make an image width 100% of parent div, but not bigger than its own width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463664/make-an-image-width-100-of-parent-div-but-not-bigger-than-its-own-width)
However when using it in a different context it's still growing above it's natural size.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

figure img {
  /* This image should shrink in a responsive way
            but not grow above it's natural size */
  max-width: 100%;
}

section p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <h4>The headline</h4>
    <img src="images/the-img.jpg">
    <figcaption>
      The caption.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</section>
```

Is there a way to pretend growing by CSS? Achieving this by Javascript would be no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your image in a div and the `max-width:100%` will be based on that rather than the flex container.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

section p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <h4>The headline</h4>
    <div><!-- added this -->
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/300">
    </div><!-- added this -->
    <figcaption>
      The caption.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, it's working fine. As the size of the figure is defined by flex:1 a gap originates when the width is large, however I can go with this.

Answer (score 2):

You want an image to shrink but not grow above its natural size. you can achieve this by

**Solution 1**: using a combination of `max-widt`h and `align-self` properties.
just modify the css of **img** element as:

```
    figure img {
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      align-self: flex-start; 
    }
```

In the figure **img** selector, we set the `width` and `height` properties to `auto` to maintain the aspect ratio of the image. The `max-width` property restricts the image from growing horizontally beyond its natural size. By setting `align-self: flex-start`, we align the image to the top of the container, allowing it to stretch vertically within the available space

**Solution 2**: the same can be achieved by setting an additional `align-items` property to `flex-start`, `center` or `flex-end` on the `figure` css. that will also prevent the stretching of inner **img** element beyond its natural width.

```
    figure {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't post the HTML you are referring to: With or without auxiliary div. I tried some variations but didn't get a satisfying result.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled a bit more and in the end got rid of the gap: Set flex-basis of the container at the right to 50% and allow it to grow.

```
        section {
            display: flex;
        }

        figure {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-basis: auto;
            flex-grow: 0;
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }

        figure img {
            /* This image should shrink in a responsive way
            but not grow above it's natural size */
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        section p {
            flex-basis: 50%;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }
```

HTML as posted by @Adam